# Boolean logic in filters when loading parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, boolean-logic

I want to remove persons that are born in 1900 and have not died yet.

Code below works, but I need two filters to remove specific rows. Is there a simpler way to remove the rows with one filter?

Minimal code to reproduce:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    (1900, None,),  # needs to be removed
    (1900, 2000,),
    (2000, None,),
    (2000, 2020,),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['birth', 'death'])
df.to_parquet('test.parquet')

# Rows which do not match the filter predicate will be removed
filters= [
    [
        ('birth', '!=', 1900),
    ],
    [
        ('birth', '=', 1900),
        ('death', 'not in', [None]),
    ]
]

df2 = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet', filters=filters)
df2.head()
```

Documentation: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_table.html#pyarrow.parquet.read_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need the `('birth', '=', 1900)` condition, you can keep rows that are `(NOT BIRTH == 1900) OR (DEATH NOT IN NONE)`, equivalent to `NOT (BIRTH == 1900 AND DEATH IN NONE)`:

```
filters= filters= [[('birth', '!=', 1900)], [('death', 'not in', [None])]]

df2 = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet', filters=filters)
```

You could also use:

```
import pyarrow.compute as pc
filters = (pc.field('birth')!=1900) | ~pc.field('death').isin([None])

# or 
filters = ~( (pc.field('birth')==1900) & pc.field('death').isin([None]) )
```

Output:

```
   birth   death
0   1900  2000.0
1   2000     NaN
2   2000  2020.0
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. Especially the `pc.field` is handy, since it allows for more freedom (i.e. not a forced OR in the 'outer layer')